# split of query of queries furthur into sections

Tags: coldfusion

I have this gist, which is working good

https://trycf.com/gist/02aa310c51203a969de35086f78c9a73/lucee5?theme=monokai

```
<cfset users = queryNew("id,username,password,section","varchar,varchar,varchar,varchar", [
   {
      "id":1,
      "username":"bob",
      "password":"unicoron",
      "section" : "Page1"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "username":"scott",
      "password":"ilikesoccer",
      "section" : "Page2"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "username":"todd",
      "password":"icheatoncod",
      "section" : "Page2"
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "username":"ray",
      "password":"icodesmelly",
      "section" : "Page2"
   }
])>
<cfdump var="#users#">
<cfoutput>
<cfloop query="users" group="section">
    <cfquery name="abc" dbtype="query">
        select * from users where section = '#section#'
    </cfquery>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><strong>#ReReplace(section,"\b(\w)","\u\1","ALL")#</strong></legend>
        <cfoutput query='abc'>
            #username# - #password# - #section#<br/>
        </cfoutput>
    </fieldset>
</cfloop>   
</cfoutput>
```

but i am trying to split the first query itself so i do not have to loop the query with group, i want to use structures, like a dynamic structure that every structure has the query above gist(the first one in gist) to splitted based upon the sections.

How can i do it, any idea?

Comment: I don't mean to sound preachy, but any time I see `cfquery` and `#password#` on the same page, I shudder a little bit. If this is demo code, please change it so that future readers don't see it as an example of how to display a password from the database. If this isn't demo code, please change it because you shouldn't ever have a need to display passwords from the database. Then change your login process so you aren't storing plain-text or recoverable passwords in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend getting away from query of query, especially if there is an unknown number of them as they are quite slow.

Here is an approach that puts data into structure and arrays to keep them in the original order.

```
<cfset sections = {} />
<cfset sectionsArray = [] />
<cfloop query="users">
    <cfif not structKeyExists(sections, users.section)>
        <cfset sections[users.section] = [] />
        <cfset arrayAppend(sectionsArray, users.section) />
    </cfif>
    <cfset arrayAppend(sections[users.section], users.currentRow) />
</cfloop>
<cfdump var="#sections#" />
<cfoutput>
<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(sectionsArray)#" index="i">
    <cfset section = sectionsArray[i] />
    <fieldset>
        <legend><strong>#ReReplace(section,"\b(\w)","\u\1","ALL")#</strong></legend>
        <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(sections[section])#" index="u">
            <cfset row = sections[section][u] />
            #users.username[row]# - #users.password[row]# - #users.section[row]#<br/>
        </cfloop>
    </fieldset>
</cfloop>   
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: When I first read about QoQ years ago, I thought it was great. Then the more I learned about it's `"intricacies"`, the less I liked it. It has its place, but that place is significantly smaller than I initially thought it was. And since CF query objects are essentially an array of structs, a lot of other methods can be used to work with them (as your example shows).

Answer (score 1):

You were close, but I think what you were going for was a grouped `<cfoutput>`.  In order to use that properly, you would first need your result set ordered by the group attribute, which in your situation is `group="section"`.  So I recoded your query to order by section.  Once that was done, the rest is easy.  Link to working gist
https://trycf.com/gist/0fb78c3640501cbadaa398e66c626500/lucee5?theme=monokai

### **EDIT**

Added CFML comments to the code sample based on feedback from the comments section below.

```
<cfset users = queryNew("id,username,password,section","varchar,varchar,varchar,varchar", [
   {
      "id":1,
      "username":"bob",
      "password":"unicoron",
      "section" : "Page1"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "username":"scott",
      "password":"ilikesoccer",
      "section" : "Page2"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "username":"todd",
      "password":"icheatoncod",
      "section" : "Page2"
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "username":"ray",
      "password":"icodesmelly",
      "section" : "Page2"
   }
])>

<!--- Re-ordered via QoQ for demo purposes only. This should be ordered in the original select --->
<cfquery name="users" dbtype="query">
    select * from users order by section
</cfquery>
<cfdump var="#users#">

<cfoutput query="users" group="section">
    <!--- Code here is outputted once per group defined above. --->
    <fieldset>
        <legend><strong>#ReReplace(section,"\b(\w)","\u\1","ALL")#</strong></legend>
        <cfoutput>
            <!--- Code is outputted here for every row in the query. --->
            #username# - #password# - #section#<br/>
        </cfoutput>
    </fieldset>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: It would be _MUCH_ easier to just `ORDER BY` in the original query than to run a second QoQ (which is significantly less efficient) to just change the order.

Comment: True, though my take was the QoQ was just for demo purposes since the snippet uses QueryNew().

Comment: @Shawn Thanks @Ageax for answering this for me.  It was for demo purposes only because the original query was not ordered, so the only way to order it was via QoQ.  Agreed that the original query should when run from a select statement should have the proper `order by` clause in it.

Comment: @user12031119 Depending on the version of CF, a QoQ is not the "only" way to sort. The resultset of a `cfquery` is essentially an array of structs, and different operations can be applied on the query object to get the result you want. Or if 2016+, you can use a `querysort` function: `sortedUsers = users.sort(
    function (el1, el2){
        return compare(el1.section, el2.section);
    }
) ;`  My recommendation would still be to go back to the initial query and send it correctly the way you need it.

Comment: @Shawn I agree that it should be sorted on the original query.  But I based my code snippet off the OP's code snippet and built from that, hence, the QoQ.  Yes, your custom `querySort` is another available tool, but the OP never specified the version they are using, so I went with what easily works in all versions.

Comment: @user12031119 Wasn't meaning to sound like I was criticizing the answer, so I do apologize. QoQ is easy, and on a small result set, it'll probably be good enough for many applications. But when you get a bunch of rows, QoQ will be much slower than just manipulating the object. I'd hate for future readers to come along and think how slow CF is because they tried to sort a million row query inside of a QoQ. Manipulating result sets should almost always be done in the database instead of the application. QoQ was a good addition to CF, but it's held developers back from learning enough SQL.

Comment: Also, I believe you could fall back into Java sorting of the query object all the way back to CF8. And if you are using anything older than that, you have more problems than needing to sort a query. Especially if that query is touching anything in a database that holds usernames and passwords in plaintext.

Comment: @Shawn  I'm all about delivering the most performant solution possible when delivering production code for my clients.  I always code my apps using the more powerful DMBS for selecting and sorting result sets.  The only time I use a QoQ in production code is when the result set is small and is already in memory and it saves a an extra round trip call to the database.  I built my code sample on tryCF.com which has no database attached, so QoQ was the easiest option to demo a code solution for ease of understanding.

Comment: Yep, there are several options for sorting IF it's actually needed :-) The OP doesn't mention why they can't use group. Unless there's a compelling reason, creating a bunch of extra structures seems less efficient than grouping IMO.